# Blackberry apps still showing phonegap logo as icon

Tags: xml, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have successfully deployed my phonegap apps to iOS, and Android Platform. The phonegap that i'm using is phonegap build. However for blackberry my apps rejected because the icon that shown in device is the phonegap logo.
I export my android apk to bar file using blackberry command line tools.

I already check my config.xml and change some settings  and install the BB10 simulator but still not found the issue, this is my config.xml

Is the problem in my xml file or because i converted my apk to bar file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.my.apps"
    version   = "1.1.0">

<name>MyApps</name>

<description>
    My apps
</description>

<author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
    Steven Smith
</author>


----cut...

<icon src="icon.png" />    
<icon src="img/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="img/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="img/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
```

```
<icon src="img/logoBB.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="img/logoBB.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="androidlogo.jpg"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="androidlogo.jpg"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="androidlogo.jpg"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="androidlogo.jpg" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Appreciate any help..
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just package it directly to .bar? It might help you solve the confusion

Comment: hi Bojan, thanks for the tips. I will try that, and also the answer from Luca.thanks

Answer (score 2):

converting a Phonegap app from APK to BAR will result in poorer performance due to the nature of the webview in the Android runtime. 
The same HTML5 code could perform much faster if packaged directly into a BAR file using Cordova.

The quickest route is to install WebWorks SDK (it's the UI for BlackBerry/Cordova apps) that can help you manage BlackBerry specific plugins or permissions.
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/
In addition it will automatically create a config.xml with the right syntax.
All you have to do is to copy your files in the www directory and use the same Cordova commands you are used to.

The icons will then be specified simply by adding:

```
<icon src="img/logoBB.png" />
```

in your config.xml. You can also specify icons for different resolutions and locales (languages)

Lastly, this is a great page that explains what you need to know when packaging a Phonegap/Cordova app for BlackBerry:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_0/porting_from_cordova.html#sey1381954510440

Cheers, 
Luca

Comment: Hi Luca, i will check this. Thanks btw